# Unable to deactivate Email Verification Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, authentication, verification

I originally thought it was a good idea to activate the email verification feature in Laravel but have decided not to use it in the end. However, for some reason, I now get an error message when I remove `['verify' => true]`  from:

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

From what I can remember it's not activated anywhere else (also from reading the docs) but I must be wrong.

Anyway, some guidance would be much appreciated, have search high and low, doing the activation in reverse etc.

This is the error message I get when I remove `['verify' => true]`.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add your user model?

Comment: Are you implementing the `MustVerifyEmail` contract in your `User` (or any `Notifiable`) model? (`class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail { ... }`)

Comment: Yes, but I thought that came set up by default and that it was envoked when you passed the verify=true parameter. What should it look like without the email of verification?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of error msg and code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  Edit your question and add the actual text, so that others with the same problem can find it.

Answer (score 11):

To desactivate Email verification :
remove ['verify' => true] from Auth::routes() in web.php 
remove "implements MustVerifyEmail" from User Model

Comment: I do that. Result: "Target class [verified] does not exist.",
"exception": "Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException".

Comment: I turn back 'verified' middleware in kernel.php, now i get error "Your email address is not verified."

Comment: I think it's because i turn off automatic login after registration. Verified middleware return that error "Your email address is not verified." if user not logged in.

Comment: Solved. To fix need also remove all `verified` middlewares from `routes/web.php` groups

Answer (score 3):

in `AuthController.php`
comment out `// $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();`

in `App\Models\User.php` comment out `// implements MustVerifyEmail`

Answer (score 2):

To deactivate Email verification :

1. Add the below line in **web.php**

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => false]);
```

2. Remove `MustVerifyEmail` interface from User Models

```php
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
 ...
}
```

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
 ...
}
```